# How do I use TDD to create a database representation of existing objects?

Tags: python, database, django, tdd

I have used TDD to develop a set of classes in Python. These objects contain data fields, functions and links to each other. Everything functionally works like I want.

Eventually all of this should be stored in a database, to be used in a Django web application.

I have sketched some possible database schema's to hold the same information, but I feel this is a "sudden big leap", compared to the traditional TDD way of developing the rest of the application.

So, now I wonder, which tests should I write to force me to store these objects in a database in a step-by-step TDD way?

Making this question a bit more concrete, the classes are currently like this:

```
class Connector(object):
  def __init__(self, title = None):
    self.value = None
    self.valid = False
    self.title = title
  ...

class Element(object):
  def __init__(self, title = None):
    self.title = title
    self.input_connectors = []
    self.output_connectors = []
    self.number_of_runs = 0

  def run(self):
    ...
    self.number_of_runs += 1

class Average(Element):
  def __init__(self, title = None):
    super(OpenCVMean, self).__init__(title = title)
    self.src = Connector("source")
    self.avg = Connector("average")
    self.input_connectors.append(self.src)
    self.output_connectors.append(self.avg)

  def run(self):
    super(Average, self).run()
    self.avg.set_value(numpy.average(self.src.value))
```

I realize some of the data should be in the database, while processing functions should not. I think there should be a table which represents the details of the different "types / subclasses " of Element, while also one which stores actual instances. But, as I said, I don't see how to get there using TDD.

Comment: Oh, there is a typo in your example. I think you meant `super(Average, self)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, ask yourself if you will be testing your code or the Django ORM. Storing and reading will be fine most of the time.

The things you will need to test are validating the data and any properties that are not model fields. I think you should end up with a good schema through writing tests on the next layer up from the database.

Also, use [South](http://south.aeracode.org/) or some other means of migration to reduce the cost of schema change. That will give you some peace of mind.

If you have several levels of tests (eg. integration tests), it makes sense to check that the database configuration is intact. Most of the tests do not need to hit the database. You can do this by mocking the model or some database operations (at least `save()`). Having said that, you can check database writes and reads with this simple test:

```
def test_db_access(self):
    input = Element(title = 'foo')
    input.save()

    output = Element.objects.get(title='foo')

    self.assertEquals(input, output)
```

Mocking save:

```
def save(obj):
    obj.id = 1
```

Comment: Thanks for the pointer to South. From reading about it, it seems certainly something that will be needed if I want to build my database schema "gradually".

As for the initial question, I still need some test that would force me to use a database. One possibility I see is maybe a test like this:

element1 = Element(title = "blah")
element2 = Element.get(title = "blah")
self.assertEqual(element1, element2)

Would that be a good way of introducing database storage through tests?